# Using Gulp 4 with ES6 - Issue with Babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, gulp, babeljs

I want to be able to have a global Gulp configuration with ES6 syntax.

I've been migrating to Gulp 4 and found good opportunity to use ES6 syntax. However I use a one single Gulp configuration for all projects.

**The problem**

Babel

Everything works fine when Gulp is located on the same folder as the project, however when I move this outside of the project it doesn't seems to interpret the Babel config - errors out as if Babel hasn't been configured.

```
$ gulp
Requiring external module @babel/register
/usr/local/share/build/gulp-babel/tasks/build.js:7
import {series, parallel} from 'gulp';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:656:28)
    at Module._compile (node_modules/@babel/register/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (node_modules/@babel/register/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
```

**File structure**

```
- ProjectFolder/
    build/
    public/
    My/Shared/Gulp -> Symlink
    gulpfile.js -> Gets the gulpfile.babel.js via require() or import

- /My/Shared/Gulp/
    tasks/
    node_modules/
    .babelrc
    gulpfile.babel.js -> this has been tested and works fine when in project folder
```

**Note**: `My/Shared/Gulp` in the `ProjectFolder` is a symlink

**Things I've tried and *didn't work***

- Created Babel configuration files on both folders, using `.babelrc` and `babel.config.js`
- Created a `package.json` file with Babel configuration
- On local `gulpfile.js` use both:

  - `require('global/gulpfile.babel.js')`
  - `import {build} from '/My/Shared/Gulp/tasks/build';`
- Renamed `gulpfile.js` to `gulpfile.babel.js` and include `.babelrc` in project folder
- Create a symbolic link to global Gulp file

Basically, I think need a global `babel.config.js` somewhere.

Any ideas would be much much appreciated! Thanks in advance